# Show div on google maps full screen

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a simple map and a marker, when I click on the marker it opens a div, How ever when in full screen the div will not show.
Is there a way for it to show in full screen?
The id of the div is "divbox"

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <style>
#divbox{
display: none;
}
    .mapbox {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
              #map {
                height: 100%;  /* The height is 400 pixels */
                width: 100%;  /* The width is the width of the web page */
               }
            </style>
          </head>
          <body>
    <div class="mapbox">
            <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="divbox">
    You clicked on a marker"
    </div>
    </div>
            <script>
        function initMap() {
          var uluru = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};
          var map = new google.maps.Map(
              document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
        }
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {document.getElementById('divbox').style.display = "block";});

            </script>
            <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
            </script>
          </body>
        </html>
```